# how to use 'or' statement in ngif in angular4?

Tags: angular, logical-or

I am using the angular4, my code below is trying to display the information basesd on the state variable.

```
<div *ngIf="state!='open' || state!='canceled'"> something </div>
```

I am using  '||' to represent the 'or' statement.

now the state variable = 'canceled', usually it should not display 'something', however in the test 'something' text is still there.

if i used the statement below, it works that the 'something' text disappear.

```
<div *ngIf="state!='canceled'"> something </div>
```

if i used the statement, it still doesn't work so it doesn't seem to be the ordering issue.

```
<div *ngIf="state!='canceled'"|| state!='open'  > something </div>
```

anything wrong?

Comment: You have typo mistake. remove `>` before `*ngIf`

Comment: If the syntax is OK, than you should provide information about where and how the state variable is being initialized

Comment: state != 'open' gives TRUE, and ngIf will evaluate the condition as TRUE and show the div.

Comment: Your condition is always true. You probably need `&&` instead of `||`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a logic error. if the variable is equal to cancel also is different to open, so the result of the conditional will be true.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only issue here is the closing of the opening  tag before your ngIf logic.

Comment: sorry, that is my mistake, it is a closed div tag.

Answer (score 0):

**ngIf** must be included inside the div tag like any regular HTML attribute.